# Integration by parts? Or does not

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

It is known that the following integrals can be solved like this:

$$I_1=\int{xe^xdx}=xe^x-e^x+C_1$$
$$I_2=\int{(xe^x)^2dx}=\frac 1 2x^2e^{2x}-\frac 1 2 xe^{2x}+\frac 1 4e^{2x}+C_2$$

What about $\int{(xe^x)^\sqrt2dx}$ or $\int{(xe^x)^edx}$?

Comment: These integral re part of a special series of integrals, known as "Incomplete Gamma Functions."

Comment: Not sure the integrals you mention will have a special form. On the other hand, if you have $(xe^x)^m$ where $m$ is a positive integer then integration by parts and an induction argument will work.

Comment: Integration by parts will not work unless the exponents is a nonnegative integer. That's said, for noninteger exponents, these integrals are expressed in terms if incomplete gamma functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let,
$$
I_a=\int (xe^x)^a\,\mathrm dx.
$$
If $a$ is a nonnegative integer we may evaluate $I_a$ in closed-form using repreated integration by parts. If, however, $a$ is not a nonnegative integer integration by parts no longer works and we instead perform the substitution $u=-ax$ to write
$$
\begin{align}
I_a
&=(-a)^{-a-1}\int u^ae^{-u}\,\mathrm du\\
&=(-a)^{-a-1}\int_0^u t^ae^{-t}\,\mathrm dt\\
&=(-a)^{-a-1}\gamma(a+1,u)+C\\
&=(-a)^{-a-1}\gamma(a+1,-a x)+C,
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma(s,z)$ is the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). Indeed, if $a=n=0,1,2,\dots$  we may use the specialized value found [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html) to write
$$
I_n=(-n)^{-n-1} n!\left(1-e^{ax}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-ax)^k}{k!}\right)+C,
$$
which is the solution you would obtain via integration by parts.